# ubuntu attempts to connect to USB-to-Ethernet adapter

Tags: networking, ethernet

Running guest Ubuntu 16.04 on a Windows 10 host in a Virtual Box. I have a USB-to-Ethernet adapter. Every time I connect it to my machine Ubuntu disconnects me from internet and attempts to connect me to my ethernet adapter "thinking" this where internet is coming from. I have to manually stop it doing it and then reconnect to internet again. I'm not a Linux pro and don't know how to to stop this behavior. Is there a way just to connect my USB-to-Ethernet adapter without disconnecting me from internet?

P.S. I'm using a USB-to-Ethernet adapter to connect to the development board. Both adapter and the board have static IP addresses. I assign the address to the adapter after it is connected to my machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to have USB devices to pass through to the guest you can disable USB passthrough in your VB settings.

*VM settings > USB > Enable USB Controller*

You can also blacklist the USB device.

*Look here https://projectgus.com/2014/09/blacklisting-a-single-usb-device-from-linux/*

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do need to use USB devices in a guest OS